# How to derive voltage output formula for a strain gauge?

Tags: strain-gage

[image]

Here is the strain gauge and its voltage output depending on its parameters such as R and excitation voltage. I couldnt derive how this is obtained analytically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of this (bridge) circuit as two simple potential dividers

[image]

R3 and R4 divide the excitation voltage in the ratio

V1 =  R4/(R3 +R4)  * E

R2 an R1 divide the excitation voltage in the ratio

V2 =  R1/(R2 + R1)  *E

The output voltage, e, is the difference between V1 and V2 (assuming no current is taken by the measuring equipment)

Comment: but v1 and v2 are always connected directly to the inputs of an instrumentation amplifier. which means v1 must be v1 = -v2. is that how it is in your figure? or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user16307  V1 is a fixed voltage. V1 and V2 are both positive voltages so **V1 is definitely NOT -V2**. As your original diagram and question do not mention an instrumentation amplifier connection it would be impossible for me to answer in those terms. However, the purpose of an instrumentation amplifier would be to amplify **the difference** between the fixed voltage, V1 and the variable voltage, V2. The output being A*(difference V1,V2) where A is the amplification factor. *For example* if V1 = 3.3V and V2 = 3.29V and A was 100 the output would be 100(3.30-3.29) = 1V

Comment: if V1 = 3.3V and V2 = 3.29V as in ur example. will the in-amp take the inputs like this: since vcm= (3.3 + 3.29)/2 = 3.295 so vin1 = 0.005 and vin2 = -0.005? im asking because all tutorials show inamp inputs same in magnitude but opposite phase.

Comment: do u think my understanding is true?

Comment: @user16307 This is a totally different question to the one asked originally and as per the rules of this site I would suggest you ask this as another question rather than try to deal with it here in comments which do not allow diagrams or a more rigorous explanation or others to answer it.

Comment: but thats the reason i asked this question:( please just say yes or no to my question if u dont have time to explain it. is my understanding right?

Comment: It doesn't look correct to me. The instrument amp is usually made up from two input buffer op amps (non inverting) followed by a differential amp. You seem to be inverting the input voltage before its (phase) inverted by the (-) input of the differential amplifier. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier